# How to pass IDbConnection to EF context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Entity Framework cotext *DbContext* has constructor which takes DbConnection. Why not IDbConnection?

Is it normally to pass DbConnection to EF context instead of using default constructor (which reads connection string from App.config?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Entity Framework cotext DbContext has constructor which takes DbConnection. Why not IDbConnection?

As i'm not part of the EF team, i can't say anything on their behalf. It seems to me like `DbConnection`, as an abstract base already has some of the implementations made for you, so you any overriden class gets things "for free".

I've found a decent answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/759fa77b-8269-4c4a-be90-3c2bdce61d92/dbconnection-vs-idbconnection?forum=adodotnetdataproviders):

> One of the main benefits has to do with versioning.  As Microsoft adds new functionality to the providers they need to expose this functionality to the developer.
>
> Using the old interface only approach, they would have to change the interface ( but they wouldn't because interfaces are immutable ) and all class implementing the interface in the framework.  Any custom classes written by Developers implementing the interface would also need to be modified to implement any changes to the interface.  If they keep adding new features ( which they will ), this becomes a vicious cycle of needing to change interfaces or implementing new ones to offer new functionality.

---

> Is it normally to pass DbConnection to EF context instead of using default constructor?

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604(v=vs.113).aspx) are pretty clear on why you'd use this overload:

> Constructs a new context instance using **the existing connection** to connect to a database. The connection will not be disposed when the context is disposed if contextOwnsConnection is false.

If you already have an open context and would like to pass that around, you can do so. *"Is it normal"* will vary for each use case. I myself haven't used this overload at all.